# How to access Firestore clearPersistence() method in Flutter using Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

How can I access the clearPersistence() Firestore method in Flutter using Dart? I need to clear the local Firestore cache when a user signs out when testing my app.

Comment: It doesn't exist yet.  File a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire).  Note that clearPersistence is not meant for the normal functioning of your app, [as described in the API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#clearPersistence()).  It's meant for testing only.

Answer (score 0):

while signing Out,

USE this --v

FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();